# Installing Data Loader on Windows

Tags: data-loader

I'm on a new computer and I haven't downloaded Data Loader in years but now, I'm having all kinds if issues.

So apparently, I have to download Zulu JDK 11 (msi) first, *Then* download and unzip Data Loaded and install. Which opens a command prompt... After I follow all of the command prompt steps, then I get an error.

Am I supposed to install Java too? And if so, do I download Java or Zulu first?

Apparently a lot of people are having this same problem with no resolve.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. What kind of error do you receive? Please edit your question and provide enough details to know what's exactly an issue here.

Answer (score 5):

You have to install the Zulu JDK first by launching the `msi`. JDK is Java Development Kit, it contains the Java runtime. Zulu is just the name/flavor of the JDK release. You also have to make sure the Java runtime from Zulu JDK is either the only Java runtime on your device or it is the runtime that you use to launch Data Loader via `PATH`.

Try this:

0. Make sure you're running the [latest release of Data Loader](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/releases). Over time, the startup scripts that ship with Data Loader have been improved.
1. Install Zulu JDK v11 or later
2. Open a command shell. Verify that `ZULU_JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set by executing this command in your shell:

```
echo %ZULU_JAVA_HOME%
```

If Zulu JDK is installed and the variable is set, it'll show you a valid path

3. Run Data Loader by launching `dataloader.bat`. The `.bat` script will use `ZULU_JAVA_HOME` to find the Java runtime.